# typeerror:not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

i've been writing this program for encryption of messages by ceasar's method, but i have a major problem with this error. it is supposed to change the string b into c and c has to be encrypted. however nothing shows up in tkinter.i have seen several similar question regarding this error but none seemed to have any connection to this case.could someone help??here is the code.

```
def encrypt(event):
global top,c,root,e
a=e.get()
b=l.get()
top.destroy()
c=''
mystring=StringVar()
mystring.set(c)
for i in b:
    if ord(i)in range(65,91) or ord(i) in range(97,123):
        if ((ord(i)+a%26)>90 and ord(i)<=90) or (ord(i)+a%26)>122:
            c=c+chr(ord(i)+a%26-26)
        else:
            c=c+chr(ord(i)+a%26)
    else:
        c=c+i
mystring.set(c)
Label(root,textvariable=mystring,bg='blue',fg='white',font=("Helvetica", 30)).pack()
root.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.get()` *probably* is returning a string. You have set `a = e.get` then, later on, you do `a % 26`. The `%` is modulo for an int, but is string formatting for a string. If a isn't a proper string for formatting (e.g. `"There were %s cows!"`), it will throw that `TypeError`. Test this by using IDLE's standard debugger or putting prints to print the value of each variable for testing.

Comment: Not "probably returning a string", but _definitely_ returning a string.

Comment: The question wasn't about a custom object, and neither was your answer. If you're calling `get` on an entry widget, you will always get a string.